# Is it possible to put an Image on a colored Rectangle with iText?

Tags: java, itext

I'm working on a Java project and I'd like to know if iText allows to put an Image object on a Rectangle object (this rectangle is filled with a color). In alternative, if it is not possible, how can I do? Thanks!

Comment: It's easy to put an image on a colored rectangle. What did you try (show us your code)? What was the problem you experienced? Which version of iText are you using?

Comment: When I try to put the image on the rectangle, this is positioned below the rectangle and not above as I'd like. The version of iText is 5.5.12

Comment: The current version is iText 7.1.0; iText 5.5.12 is a *maintenance release*. I assumed that your use case was adding an image on top of a rectangle, in which case I'd either have defined a border for the image, or an image wrapped in a `Chunk` and a background defined for the chunk. Wouldn't that be easier to achieve? Also: what you describe only happens if you add the image with `Document.add()`, not with `PdfContentByte.addImage()`. I already see a down-vote and a close vote. That's because you don't show your code. It you want help, please don't make us guess what you're doing. Show code!

Comment: I use `PdfContentByte.addImage()` and it works! Thanks!

Comment: I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably adding the rectangle using `PdfContentByte` and the behavior you described tells me that you are adding the `Image` using `document.add()`.

If you obtained the `PdfContentByte` using `PdfWriter.getDirectContent()`, all the content you add to that canvas will be *on top of* the content you add with `Document.add()`. You should use `PdfWriter.getDirectContentUnder()` if you want it the other way round.

However, since you already have a `PdfContentByte` instance anyway, it could be easier to replace:

```
document.add(image);
```

with:

```
pdfContentByte.addImage(image);
```

That way, the image will also cover the rectangle (provided that you add the image *after* drawing the rectangle).